# How to do Gridview Datakey value at @nd page of gridview?

Tags: asp.net

The Problem is:

i have a gridview to bind with 20 records  & its allowpaging is true,but pageindexchanging event is not fired & pagesize is10

& on rowdatabound of gridview i get datakey value for first 10 records but not get the datakey value for next 10 records(i.e. 2nd page)

& the gridview is binding for 20 records

Comment: without code how can we find exact problem?

Comment: Please post your code and the way how you are binding your Gridview.